# Damped pendulum equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation of a damped pendulum:

$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2+\sin\theta=0$$

with the pendulum starting with $0$ velocity, apparently we can derive:

$$\frac{dt}{d\theta}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt2\left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\theta\right)-e^{-(\theta+\phi)}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\phi\right)\right]}}$$

where $\phi$ is the initial angle from the vertical. How can we derive that? Obviously $\frac{dt}{d\theta}$ is the reciprical of $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, but I don't see how to deal with the second derivative.

I've found a similar derivation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics), where the formula

$${\frac {d\theta }{dt}}={\sqrt {{\frac {2g}{\ell }}(\cos \theta -\cos \theta _{0})}}$$

is derived in the "Energy derivation of Eq. 1" section. However, that uses a conservation of energy argument which is not applicable for a damped pendulum.

So how can I derive that equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$
\ddot{\theta} =\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d\theta}\dot{\theta}^2
$$
then sub in $p =\dot{\theta}^2$

you should be able to derive the formula you desire. with the suitable initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

HINT...Write $$\dot{\theta}=x$$
Then you have $$x\frac{dx}{d\theta}+\frac 12x^2+\sin\theta=0$$

This is a [Bernoulli Differential Equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation)